# Proof by Contrapositive (without using the closure property )

Tags: logic, alternative-proof

I tried to prove the ff:

If x^2 is an irrational number then x is an irrational number.

[image]

Is there another way of proving the statement by contraposition, without using the closure property of the set of rational numbers under multiplication?

Comment: Your proof is okay. Actually it will be good if you show $gcd(p^2,q^2)=1$  Maybe you can use definiton of irrational number but it would be complicated

Comment: May I ask how it can be proved using the def. of rational nos.?